# Why there is no around interceptor for the filter in grails

Tags: grails

It seems that there is no around interceptor for the filter in grails.We have the same in case of Spring.If we want to implement it as per grails format what will be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could mimic that somewhat. In the `before` closure you can check the request, session, etc. and determine whether to proceed with the regular call. If you want you can redirect, or render a response in the filter, and return `false` to indicate that the controller shouldn't be called.

If you want to allow the controller to proceed, you can then do work in the `after` closure. You can store information in request scope in the `before` closure (e.g. `request.currentRequestNumber = counter.incrementAndGet()`) and retrieve it in the `after` closure (e.g. `int currentRequestNumber = request.currentRequestNumber`) taking advantage of using property access to store and retrieve request attributes.

You cannot however "call" the controller and inspect its result, and choose whether to send that response, or modify it, or send a different response. You could probably do that with a response wrapper though, where you have a custom writer that captures the rendered response.

Note that you have more flexibility (but less Grails/Groovy help) with a regular servlet filter, i.e. a class that implements `javax.servlet.Filter` and is registered in web.xml.